# Find and delete row from cell array

Tags: matlab

```
A = {'A1'; 'A2'; 'A3'}
```

I need to find and delete row contain 'A2'(char)
Result:

```
A = 'A1'
    'A3'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it seems your code is growing very slowly and for every second line you post a question here. When have the SO users finished your project? Maybe you should start to try things out ;) Not that there is much wrong with your questions, but you would learn more by a little more own effort ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is not a matrix, it is a cell array.

So you may use `cellfun` to perform operations on cells. In your case, and in a short way:

```
A(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,'A2'), A)) = [];
```

I've created an anynomous function which compares the content of each cell to the string "A2"; applying this to the whole cell array gives me a mask of the cells to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `ismember`'s second output for this:

```
[~, ind] = ismember('A2',A)
A(ind) =[]
```

Or in 1 line using `strcmp`:

```
A = A(~strcmp(A,'A2'))
```